# How to get correct color and /or stencil-renderable internal format supported by current implementation?

Tags: opengl, off-screen

Using OpenGL FBO to do Offscreen rendering. Main code fragment of creating FBO is listed bellow:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);

// Create new framebuffers with new size.
int maxSize; glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE,  &maxSize);
glGenRenderbuffers(1,&clrRbo)
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,clrRbo);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8, (std::min)(maxSize,m_localvp.pix_width),(std::min)(maxSize, m_localvp.pix_height));

glGenRenderbuffers(1,&stencilRbo);  
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,stencilRbo); 
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_INDEX8, (std::min)(maxSize,m_localvp.pix_width),(std::min)(maxSize, m_localvp.pix_height));

// Bind new framebuffers to FBO;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, clrRbo);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, stencilRbo);
// Checke FBO status
checkFramebufferStatus();
```

The code above works for some of the graphic hardware, but fails on others. And the error reported in glCheckFramebufferStatus() is GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED which means the internal format of color or stencil format is non-renderable.

How can I get the correct color or stencil-renderable internal format supported on the graphic hardware where the code run? Or, how can I make my code portable across different OpenGL versions and hardware implementations?

**MY research:**

- glGetInternalformat() is only supported in OpenGL 4.1 or higher. If I can get the same functionality of this function in older OpenGL versions?
- [This](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xml) says GL_STENCIL_INDEX8 is the only stencil-renderable format, is that correct? It fails to function in my code.
- [This doc](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glRenderbufferStorage.xhtml) shows all the supported formats enums. What's the difference between internal formats and base formats.

Answer (score 2):

`glGetInternalFormat()` was new functionality in OpenGL 4.2. There is no way to get the same information in earlier versions.

I'm not convinced that it would give you all you need anyway. While it provides a ton of information about each format, which looks partly helpful for the purpose, it still does not tell you which **combinations** of formats are valid as FBO attachments. `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED` is not based on each format individually being renderable, but the combination of them. From the spec:

> The combination of internal formats of the attached images does not violate an implementation-dependent set of restrictions.

If you used an attachment that does not use a renderable format, you would in fact get a `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_INCOMPLETE` value.

To find a combination of formats that is supported by a given implementation, your best bet is to try a few combinations that can support the functionality you need. I would try them in order of preference, until you find a combination where `glCheckFramebufferStatus()` succeeds.